# collection_radio_buttons does not render values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-group

I am stuck on a form that should give me inline group of radios. Code below:

```
...
  <%= f.fields_for :logo do |logo_fields| %>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= logo_fields.label :business, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= logo_fields.collection_radio_buttons :business, Order.bu, :first, :last do |b| %>
          <%= b.label(class: 'radio inline') { b.radio_button + b.text} %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
...
```

I am using a class method here `Order.bu`, which returns an array `[[:st, "ST"], [:gp, "GP"], [:none, "none of them"]]` used in collection_radio_buttons.

Question now why above code doesn't create html with proper values inside  fields?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered (when writing the question) that it's only DOM that doesn't have values in my radios. It turned out a buggy javascript when performing reset operation cleared all values of inputs, including radios.